# Is there any Subtext IDE or equivalent Example-driven Visual Programming Language/Interface published on the Internet?

Tags: subtext, visual-programming

I'm really excited about this new and experimental language named [Subtext](http://www.subtextual.org/). But it's author haven't released nothing about it besides some papers and videos. Should I clone it? There are similar alternatives?

**UPDATE** I'm looking for an example-driven VPL, not just a VPL.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am sure you are aware of [VPL On Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Visual_programming_language) that lists many different VPL languages. You have not supplied information on what you are trying to achieve but another site is [Synopsis](http://www.codemorphis.com/). This is a commercial product.

From their website:

> Synopsis is a completely visual RAD tool for Windows that frees you from having to write textual code and learning unnecesary programming details. With Synopsis you can concentrate on creating software instead of wrestling with mundane and complex low-level development tasks.

The image below shows how this application looks:

[image]
<sub>(source: [codemorphis.com](http://www.codemorphis.com/images/visual_programming_example.jpg))</sub>

Granted my knowledge on this subject is limited and I do follow this to see if something really powerful can be created. I did see a project on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/) or [CodePlex](http://www.codeplex.com/) that was written in C# that allowed VPL but I cant find that URL.

If I ever do find that application I will edit this post!

Answer (score 3):

As Edwards' says in his related work section, the Self programming language is very similar. It shares subtext's emphsis on directness, uniformity, and liveness, but doesn't emphasize a tabular format (Schematic tables).

A lot of of work went into the Solaris version:
  http://research.sun.com/self/papers/papers.html
seems there's a Mac & linux version, not sure how mature it is:
  http://selflanguage.org/

Here's a video demo'ing Self, where they emphasize directness, uniformity, and liveness:
  http://www.smalltalk.org.br/movies/

When you say "any VPL", do you mean none at all, or not a run-of-the-mill one?  From the wording of the title question, I'll assume the latter. Here're a couple with some serious programming theory behind them:

Morphic is/was a/the UI piece of Self, and is now ported to Squeak:
  http://wiki.squeak.org/squeak/2139

Prograph was a way-cool system, but I don't know of an available version.
A bit further out there is Kahn's Toontalk, based on Pictorial Janus:
   http://www.toontalk.com/

Answer (score 2):

You haven't provided more information about features you expect from such a VPL environment, but I think that "Tersus" could be interesting thing to look at. There're many VPLs, but mainly they're targeted as educational tools or addition to particular technologies (i.e VPL for Microsoft Robotics Studio) to simplify common tasks programming. The "Tersus" is full blown application development platform. It's open source and free to download for many OSes.

http://www.tersus.com

Answer (score 2):

Coherence — The Director’s Cut
The Coherence home page is up at http://coherence-lang.org. The submitted version of the paper is there, with a new intro and a surprise ending.

Coherence claims to be an experimental programming language, a continuation of Subtext using other means.

Answer (score 2):

Intentional shipped, but they are still kind of alpha, with limited distribution and testing.  You can make example driven DSLs, but I don't know if the environment itself works that way.

http://lambda-the-ultimate.org/node/3287

Answer (score 1):

You could look at the work on eve that is happening too:

http://incidentalcomplexity.com/